# Cannot find file or folder when running appcfg.py update myapp/

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy my application to Google App Engine from the command line.

I open the folder in which my application resides. Next I right click in the folder and click on "Open Git Bash here".

Git Bash opens up. I type:

```
appcfg.py update myapp/
```

I get the message

> /usr/bin/env: python: No such file or directory

Why is this deployment not succeeding?

I am running on Windows 8, not in a virtual machine or enviroment.

Comment: this is not a deployment issue, you need to add python to your path/environment

Comment: How do I do that? I haven't done that before. After googling for a solution I tried adding PYTHONPATH as an environment variable in system settings defined as C:\Python27\ but that didn't help.

Comment: Sorry I misread the error, if you google that error you should find multiple solutions

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Windows, try naming python explicitly.

```
python appcfg.py update myapp/
```